# Mongoose find nested object that has a dot in a key

Tags: java, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is the model, and i want to find the username using the model address.
example:

```
let query = "DepositAddress." +currency;
Wallet.findOne({ [query] : address }})
```

using this method i can find the document using the address and the currency.
but i cannot use this method to find the document with the currency USDT.ERC20 because it has a dot in it. so it looks inside usdt:{ erc20 : { . something like this but i want 'usdt.erc20': {

i hope this makes sense

```
{
    username: 'somename',
      __v: 0,
      DepositAddress: {
        ETH: '0xsjfsjfsjfsfjsp',
        BTC: 'fdsfsdfsddsfsdf',
        'USDT.ERC20': 'fdjfoidsfjfso'
      }
 }
```

Comment: Perhaps the design of the `DepositAddress` needs a change. Something like an array of sub-documents like `{  currency: 'ÚSDT.ERC20', value: 'some_value'  }` may be easy to manage.

Answer (score 0):

u can make ustd an object that has .erc20

Comment: no, its made by a api. so i cannot change the model. i just need a way to find document using the address